# how to assign a value to a list in java if i assign a following value it shows cannot convert from int[] to List<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, spring, list, integer

How to assign a value to a list in java? If Ii assign a following value it shows `cannot convert from int[] to List<Integer>`

```
public class GetAddonProductsProcessorTest {

  @Test
  public void AddonProductstest() throws Exception{
    
    //BasicDBList newobj = new BasicDBList();
      
    List<Integer> newobj = {1,2,3};
  
  }
```

Comment: Reading through the [Javadoc for List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) will help you. List is an interface, you need to instantiate a new object of a type that implements it, such as `ArrayList` and then use the corresponding methods to add things to the list.

Comment: Try `List<Integer> newobj = List.of(1, 2, 3);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create list using Arrays.asList

```
ArrayList<Integer> newObj = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
```

Comment: There is no need for `new Integer[]` as varargs will let compiler generate it for us, so we can write easier code like `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)`. Also prefer to program on interfaces (more info: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947)) so instead of `ArrayList<Integer> newObj =` use `List<Integer> newObj =` (like OP already does).